# Transformation of a vector via geometric algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-algebras

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 0 & 2 & 5 \\ 2 & 2 & 1  \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}  $

Let's take this general transformation of a vector. How do I calculate this in the framework of geometric algebra ?

Comment: You don't.$\ \ $

Comment: This question is already answered you idiots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really think that of geometric algebra (the study of certain Clifford algebras over the reals) as an *extension* of linear algebra -- not as a replacement for matrix algebra.  Geometric algebra provides new ways to describe things like subspaces, invariant subspaces, certain *specific* linear transformations like rotations and reflections, etc.  But that doesn't mean you can find an equivalent geometric algebra expression to simplify *any* given linear transformation.

So the simple answer is: you don't.

Comment: So that does mean that in GA you can't do any real calculations with numbers? Or that you don't need to do it?

Comment: You can certainly do calculations in GA.  For instance if your transformation matrix were $$\pmatrix{\cos(\pi/6) & -\sin(\pi/6) & 0 \\ \sin(\pi/6) & \cos(\pi/6) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}$$ then that same calculation could be done as $e^{-i\pi/12}(e_1 + 2e_2 + 3e_3)e^{i\pi/12}$ where $i=e_1 \wedge e_2$.  But that doesn't mean that you can replace *every* calculation in linear algebra with one in GA.

Comment: I'll reword the thesis of my answer: You should think of GA as *adding* a few new concepts and techniques to the subject of linear algebra and NOT as a *replacement* for linear algebra or even matrix algebra.

Comment: Ok thank you Bye_World ! :)