# geometric algebra expression for a linear transformation defined on basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, geometric-algebras

I have a transformation $T(u)$ between 3D vector subspaces of a 4D vector space, $A \rightarrow B$, defined by a mapping of their basis vectors:

$A:\{a_1=e_1\,,\,a_2=e_2\,,\,a_3=e_4\}$

$B:\{b_1=e_2\,,\,b_2=e_3\,,\,b_3=e_1\}$

$T(a_i)=b_i$

I have aligned each space to the standard bases in this example, but I don't want to assume that will always be the case.

My question is: Is there a general process for computing an expression in geometric algebra for this transformation? I know there are ways to define a matrix for this transformation, but is it possible using only the language of geometric algebra?

From reading *Linear and Geometric Algebra* by Alan Macdonald, I know that there are simple expressions for some classes of linear transformations like symmetric, orthogonal, and skew transformations.
For example, symmetric transformations can be expressed as   $T(u)=\sum{(u \cdot v_i)\lambda _i v_i}\;$ for normalized eigenvectors $v_i$ and eigenvalues $\lambda _i$ . It does not seem like these were found by a general method. Perhaps the best process is simply to classify the transformation and use the consequences of that classification to construct one (if possible).

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674345/transformation-of-a-vector-via-geometric-algebra), closed due to its ambiguity, this guess is correct. The accepted answer claims that geometric algebra does not have a standard representation for all linear transformations.

So, if the best process is to classify the transformation and use the consequences of that classification to construct one (if possible), I am still unsure how I should apply this to my example problem. Is there a complete way to classify the set of linear transformations defined from basis maps, and do all classifications have corresponding expressions in geometric algebra? Or, is this a misapplication of ideas, as the linked answer suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to represent all linear transformations on R^n within G^n. However the paper *Lie groups as spin groups* 
(http://bdml.stanford.edu/twiki/pub/Rise/GeomAlgebra/lie_groups.pdf) claims that it is possible with G^(n,n). For an explanation of G(n,n) see Chapter 10 of my book. I have not read the paper.

Two notes. 1. In your listing of transformations represented in GA you didn't include those from Chapter 7.

2. All of my representations are *on* a vector space. Your example is *between* two vector spaces.

Chapter 10, on the conformal model was added in later editions. It is available at the book's web site: http://www.faculty.luther.edu/~macdonal/laga/ .

Yes, you can consider your example to be *on* a vector space, but you did not phrase it that way.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that paper. My version of your book only has nine chapters, was 10 added in a later version maybe?
To your notes: 1. Yes, I did not mean for the list to be exhaustive, and it could have included Projection, Reflection, and Rotation.
2. Since my 3d vector spaces are in a 4d vector space, can't the transformation be considered a transformation on the 4d vector space?